# Windows HTTP proxy client to pass service requests to VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy

I've got access to a network via CheckPoint VPN (Windows client).

Problem is, I have a linux box that needs to talk to its web services and the target web servers are inside the VPN.

So far, we have been unable to connect linux to the VPN (and I'm not trying to solve that problem at the moment).

I'm wondering if (temporarily) I can setup a proxy server on a Windows (XP) box to shuttle HTTP requests back and forth?  If so, what'd be a good application to do this? (hopefully free/open-source)

TIA

Comment: Being able to do this will also depend on if the CheckPoint VPN setup on the Windows client allows for connections to your local LAN while connected to the VPN. It is not uncommon for that to be turned off so that the only connectivity is to and from the VPN Network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not install OpenSSH on the windows box, and then tunnel all http requests through the SSH server?

Here is one example:
http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/

and this one uses OpenSSH in the example

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: Thanks.  In the meantime they've just moved the platform to Windows so my question is moot. :(  Nice to know this is possible though.

Comment: This approach is ok if the VPN setup allows communication with the local LAN when connected. If not then the OpenSSH server on the windows box won't be accessible when connected to the VPN which defeats the point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this [Free HTTP Tesing tool](http://soft-net.net/default.aspx)